# Why do I not have syntax highlighting when I sudo vi <filename>?

Tags: linux, sudo, vi

I don't understand how to allow syntax highlighting in files I'm editing via **vi** when using sudo. When I `sudo vi <filename>` the terminal is only black & white of my terminal settings. In vi if I enter `:syntax on` nothing changes.

When I `vi <filename>` all the syntax is properly colored. Using RHEL 5.4, relevant env:

```
LS_COLORS=no=00:fi=00:di=01;34:ln=01;36:pi=40;33:so=01;35:bd=40;
33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=01;05;37;41:mi=01;05;37;41:ex=01;32:*.cmd=01;
32:*.exe=01;32:*.com=01;32:*.btm=01;32:*.bat=01;32:*.sh=01;32:*.csh=01;
32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.zip=01;
31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.rpm=01;
31:*.cpio=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;
35:*.png=01;35:*.tif=01;35:
```

---

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

---

```
TERM=xterm-color
```

Comment: `vi` doesn't support color, so anything showing color is running `vim` or similar.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Larks answer is probably the most likely. You may not wish to change your root accounts vi to vim permanently as if your resources are low vi is almost guaranteed to always work, I'm not so sure about vim.

You are probably using (color)

```
/usr/bin/vim
```

under your normal user and

```
/bin/vi
```

under sudo or root.
You can check by using:

```
which vi
```

once under your normal user and the other via sudo

```
sudo which vi
```

Do a

```
man which
```

if you need more details

Comment: I didn't change the root account to use vim but just knowing that which showed that vi was aliased to vim as my user tells me to use sudo vim <file> instead of sudo vi <file>

Answer (score 18):

On a RHEL system, `/bin/vi` is typically a minimal version of `vim`, without any syntax highlighting support.  `/usr/bin/vim` is the full-featured editor.  It is very likely that in your user environment, `vi` is an alias for `vim`.  Try this:

```
sudo vim /some/file
```

Do you get syntax highlighting now?

Comment: Yes! and it seems sinping's answer was the one I needed to get the behaviour I wanted

Answer (score 14):

Your `vi` is probably `/bin/vi` from package `vim-minimal` which does not support syntax highlighting. `sudo vi` launches `/bin/vi` for you.

Bash only does alias expansion on the first word in your command line, so in:

```
sudo vi
```

`vi` is not substituted to `vim` even if you have that alias defined.

**The solution** is define another alias (for the user invoking `sudo`):

> **alias sudo='sudo '**

Note the space after the second `sudo`.

Using this `sudo`, bash will do alias expansion for `vi` in `sudo vi`. In the `alias` section of Bash doc it says:

> If the last character of the alias value is a blank, then the next
>   command word following the alias is also checked for alias expansion.

After you enter your command, You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> in `bash` to see the expansion result.

Credits:

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=36796

http://www.shellperson.net/using-sudo-with-an-alias

---

Simply aliasing `vi` in `/root/.bashrc` will not work.

It may also be noted that `vi` is not aliased for root on some distros in /etc/profile.d/vim.sh:

```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" -o -n "$KSH_VERSION" -o -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ]; then
  [ -x /usr/bin/id ] || return
  ID=`/usr/bin/id -u`
  [ -n "$ID" -a "$ID" -le 200 ] && return
  # for bash and zsh, only if no alias is already set
  alias vi >/dev/null 2>&1 || alias vi=vim
fi
```

Changing this will not solve the problem either.

Comment: Awesome trick to have aliases with sudo!

Comment: Love this - simple and elegant!!!  This IS the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

By default in 5.4 vi is default. I forget what version that started in. This will add the necessary alias for you:

```
cat <<_EOF >>/root/.bashrc

alias "vi"="/usr/bin/vim"
_EOF
```

Answer (score 2):

i found that in my version of vim (install with `sudo apt-get install vim` on debian 7) the `syntax on` command is defined on a per-user basis in `~/.vimrc`. however by default the install did not create a `/root/.vimrc` file for `sudo vi`to load. so i just copied `~/.vimrc` into the `/root/` dir and this did the trick: `sudo cp ~/.vimrc /root/`

Answer (score 0):

1) Check if you're really using vim and not vi (which unfortunately is default often on fresh installed systems)

2) Check that your `/etc/vim/vimrc` has the line `syntax on`

3) Not all kinds of files have syntax-highlighting info available by default....

Comment: There was no /etc/vim/vimrc, but /etc/vimrc did have syntax highlighting by default:

if &t_Co > 2 || has("gui_running")
  syntax on
  set hlsearch
endif

Answer (score -1):

For those still looking for help, try these commands.

- `sudovi = which sudo vi`
- `usrvi = which vi`
- If these two locations are the same, then don't continue.

Otherwise...

- `mv $sudovi $sudovi.save`
- `ln -s $usrvi $sudovi` (symbolic link)